# SSIS: Flat file source contains column names in two rows

Tags: ssis

I have got a requirement like, I need to process a flat file with fixed width and the columns are in two columns like below

```
column1 --> Column2 -->Column3 --> Column4 -->  Column5 -->     Column6

  123         Stack    12/01/2015   Overflow    A2bg4,ghtr     $425.20  
  456          MSDN    11/30/2015   Microsoft   345GHT67e,dff  $1,254.23
```

I will get this type of files daily and I need to check for File Schema validation  every time before processing it.

My idea is using

```
SELECT @variable = DATALENGTH(column1 --> Column2 -->
                   Column3 --> Column4 -->Column5 --> Column6)
```

and compare this value with the DATALENGTH(InputFile schema COlumns).

If it is matched then the file is validated and further processed.

But, if the columns with same length are swapped like

```
column2 --> Column3 -->Column1
```

then I should  not furthur proceed.And Validation is failed.

Could anyone suggest me how to validate the input file for Schema?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In your example, lines one and three either do not have a delimiter or have space as the delimiter. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly. As i do not have any delimiter, I need to consider that file with Fixed Width format depends on the content.